# Administrator Limited Number of Outlook Items

Tags: vba, outlook

How to change the loop?

I really need help. I have a macro to download PDFs from messages with the following code:

```
Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF2()

    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim currentAttachment As Attachment
    Dim saveToFolder As String
    Dim savedFileCountPDF As Long

    saveToFolder = "c:\dev\pdf" 'change the path accordingly

    savedFileCountPDF = 0
    For Each currentItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        For Each currentAttachment In currentItem.Attachments
            If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
                currentAttachment.SaveAsFile saveToFolder & "\" & _
                    Left(currentAttachment.DisplayName, Len(currentAttachment.DisplayName) - 4) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"
                savedFileCountPDF = savedFileCountPDF + 1
            End If
        Next currentAttachment
    Next currentItem

    MsgBox "Number of PDF files saved: " & savedFileCountPDF, vbInformation

End Sub
```

I have a large number, around 4k. It only lets me do a few and then gives me this message in the title. Is there a way to change my code to tackle them in groups or one by one, rather than all at once?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try messing with the settings mentioned in [this article for that error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115602/performance-and-synchronization-problems-when-you-work-with-folders-in) ? Or maybe if possible modify your script to move each message to an archive pst after the attachments have been saved as this might remove them from the server and avoid the error?

Comment: I think I just want a way to execute it per message not in one big loop that allows it to exceed 256 messages open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try For Next to see if objects are released automatically.

If not successful, check if setting the object to nothing has an impact.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF2_ForNext()

    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim currentAttachment As Attachment
    Dim saveToFolder As String
    Dim savedFileCountPDF As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    saveToFolder = "c:\dev\pdf" 'change the path accordingly

    savedFileCountPDF = 0
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
        
        Set currentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)
    
        For j = 1 To currentItem.Attachments.Count
                    
            Set currentAttachment = currentItem.Attachments(j)
            
            If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 4)) = UCase(".PDF") Then
                currentAttachment.SaveAsFile saveToFolder & "\" & _
                  Left(currentAttachment.DisplayName, Len(currentAttachment.DisplayName) - 4) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"
                savedFileCountPDF = savedFileCountPDF + 1
            End If
            
            ' If For Next does not release memory automatically then
            '  uncomment to see if this has an impact
            'Set currentAttachment = Nothing
            
        Next
        
        ' If For Next does not release memory automatically then
        '  uncomment to see if this has an impact
        'Set currentItem = Nothing
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Number of PDF files saved: " & savedFileCountPDF, vbInformation

End Sub
```